# Redirect all subdomains of a domain to an other domain

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect all subdomains of a domain to an other domain, using htaccess. An example :

`*.domain1.com` to `*.domain2.com`

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thans. The code didn't run because of my hosting, but thanks of it, I can find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Made the www optional

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%2 [R=301,L]
```